# Overriding Magento's Google Sitemap: how to override Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Category?

Tags: magento, xml-sitemap

I'm trying to override Magento's functionality to create a sitemap.xml file (`Catalog > Google Sitemap` in the backend).
The idea of my override is that not all product- and category-URLs should be included in the sitemap, I need the category-path of a product or category to determine whether to include it or not.

So this is what I did, I added this to my module's config.xml:

```
...
<global>
    ...
    <models>
        ...
        <sitemap>
            <rewrite>
                <sitemap>Company_Module_Model_Sitemap</sitemap>
            </rewrite>
        </sitemap>
        ...
    </models>
    ...
</global>
...
```

The class `Company_Module_Model_Sitemap` is overridden well, but it turned out I also need to override the resource model to be able to achieve my goal, so I added the following to the config.xml file (between the models-tag):

```
<sitemap_resource>
    <rewrite>
        <sitemap>Company_Module_Model_Sitemap_Resource_Catalog_Category</sitemap>
    </rewrite>
</sitemap_resource>
```

Now it starts to go wrong.. It somehow won't even load the backend grid anymore, navigating to the backend page of Google Sitemap yields the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sitemap_id' in 'order clause'
```

Curently, the only content of the Company_Module_Model_Sitemap_Resource_Catalog_Category class is the following:

```
class Company_Module_Model_Sitemap_Resource_Catalog_Category
     extends Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Category { }
```

So finally, my question: how to correctly override the `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Category` class in Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! Nevermind, I found the error myself. This:

```
<sitemap_resource>
    <rewrite>
        <sitemap>Company_Module_Model_Sitemap_Resource_Catalog_Category</sitemap>
    </rewrite>
</sitemap_resource>
```

should have been this:

```
<sitemap_resource>
    <rewrite>
        <catalog_category>Company_Module_Model_Sitemap_Resource_Catalog_Category</catalog_category>
    </rewrite>
</sitemap_resource>
```